# Does a Python list contain any number more than N times?

Tags: python

In Python, I have a list of numbers. What is the easiest way to find out whether the list contains any number more than N times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 from collections import Counter
 max(Counter(my_list).itervalues()) > N
```

Comment: I see you took a different interpretation of "any number more than N times" that I did. Better to use `any` instead of `max` though I think, so it can shortcircuit -  `any(x > N for x in Counter(my_list).itervalues())`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy, I think it depends, `max` has more predictable performance: better worst case, and worse best case. `max` will be faster if no elements show more than N times. And I think most of the time will be spent constructing the `Counter` anyway, so this difference is slight. `max` golfs better, and imo is slightly more readable.

Answer (score 3):

```
if your_list.count(item) > N:
    print("it happened here")
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for *you* is probably something like

```
[x for x in set(the_list) if the_list.count(x) > N]
```

It's not the most efficient approach (**`O(n**2)`**) for the *computer* though, so another strategy is needed for large lists.

Using `collections.Counter` means the computer only needs to scan the list once, so is more efficient (**`O(n)`**)

```
from collections import Counter
[k for k, v in Counter(the_list).items() if v > N]
```